# How does this recursive List flattening work?

Tags: scala, implicit

A while back [this was asked and answered](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Simple-enough-to-describe-tp2535027p2535194.html) on the Scala mailing list:

Kevin:

> Given some nested structure: `List[List[...List[T]]]`
>   what's the best (preferably type-safe) way to flatten it to a `List[T]`

Jesper:

> A combination of implicits and default arguments works:

```
case class Flat[T, U](fn : T => List[U]) 

implicit def recFlattenFn[T, U](implicit f : Flat[T, U] = Flat((l : T) 
=> List(l))) = 
   Flat((l : List[T]) => l.flatMap(f.fn)) 

def recFlatten[T, U](l : List[T])(implicit f : Flat[List[T], U]) = f.fn(l)
```

Examples:

```
scala> recFlatten(List(1, 2, 3)) 
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3) 

scala> recFlatten(List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5))) 
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 

scala> recFlatten(List(List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5)), List(List(6, 7)))) 
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

I have been looking at this code for a while. I cannot figure out how it works. There seems to be some recursion involved... Can anybody shed some light? Are there other examples of this pattern and does it have a name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh wow, this is an old one!  I'll start by cleaning up the code a bit and pulling it into line with current idiomatic conventions:

```
case class Flat[T, U](fn: T => List[U]) 

implicit def recFlattenFn[T, U](
  implicit f: Flat[T, U] = Flat((xs: T) => List(xs))
) = Flat((xs: List[T]) => xs flatMap f.fn)

def recFlatten[T, U](xs: List[T3])(implicit f: Flat[List[T], U]) = f fn xs
```

Then, without further ado, break down the code.  First, we have our `Flat` class:

```
case class Flat[T, U](fn: T => List[U])
```

This is nothing more than a named wrapper for the function `T => List[U]`, a function that will build a `List[U]` when given an instance of type `T`.  Note that `T` here could also be a `List[U]`, or a `U`, or a `List[List[List[U]]]`, etc. Normally, such a function could be directly specified as the type of a parameter.  But we're going to be using this one in implicits, so the named wrapper avoids any risk of an implicit conflict.

Then, working backwards from `recFlatten`:

```
def recFlatten[T, U](xs: List[T])(implicit f: Flat[List[T], U]) = f fn xs
```

This method will take `xs` (a `List[T]`) and convert it to a `U`.  To achieve this, it locates an implicit instance of `Flat[T,U]` and invokes the enclosed function, `fn`

Then, the real magic:

```
implicit def recFlattenFn[T, U](
  implicit f: Flat[T, U] = Flat((xs: T) => List(xs))
) = Flat((xs: List[T]) => xs flatMap f.fn)
```

This satisfies the implicit parameter required by `recFlatten`, it also takes another implicit paramater. Most crucially:

- `recFlattenFn` can act as its own implicit parameter
- it returns a Flat[List[X], X], so `recFlattenFn` will only be implicitly resolved as a `Flat[T,U]` if `T` is a `List`
- the implicit `f` can fallback to a default value if implicit resolution fails (i.e. `T` is NOT a `List`)

Perhaps this is best understood in the context of one of the examples:

```
recFlatten(List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5)))
```

- The type `T` is inferred as `List[List[Int]]`
- implicit lookup is attempted for a `Flat[List[List[Int]], U]
- this is matched by a recursively defined `recFlattenFn`

Broadly speaking:

```
recFlattenFn[List[List[Int]], U] ( f =
  recFlattenFn[List[Int], U] ( f =
    Flat[Int,U]((xs: T) => List(xs)) //default value
  )
)
```

*Note that `recFlattenFn` will only match an implicit search for a `Flat[List[X], X]` and the type params `[Int,_]` fail this match because `Int` is not a `List`. This is what triggers the fallback to the default value.*

Type inference also works backwards up that structure, resolving the `U` param at each level of recursion:

```
recFlattenFn[List[List[Int]], Int] ( f =
  recFlattenFn[List[Int], Int] ( f =
    Flat[Int,Int]((xs: T) => List(xs)) //default value
  )
)
```

Which is just a nesting of `Flat` instances, each one (except the innermost) performing a `flatMap` operation to unroll one level of the nested `List` structure.  The innermost `Flat` simply wraps all the individual elements back up in a single `List`.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot. I think in your example the type parameters are off by a wrapping. This compiles  `recFlatten[List[Int],Int](List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5))) (
  recFlattenFn[List[Int], Int] ( f =
    recFlattenFn[Int, Int] ( f =
      Flat[Int,Int]((xs: Int) => List(xs)) //default value
    )
  )
)
`

Answer (score 2):

May be a good solution is to try to look at how the types are infered. To avoid ambiguity, let us rename the generics:

```
case class Flat[T, U](fn : T => List[U]) 

implicit def recFlattenFn[T2, U2](implicit f : Flat[T2, U2] = 
                                    Flat((l : T2) => List(l))) = 
  Flat((l : List[T2]) => l.flatMap(f.fn)) 

def recFlatten[T3, U3](l : List[T3])(implicit f : Flat[List[T3], U3]) = f.fn(l)
```

In the first case, `res0`, the type of `T3` is `Int` you cannot infer yet the type of `U3`, but you know that you will need a `Flat[List[Int, U3]]` object that will be provided implicitly. There is only one "implicit candidate": the result of the `recFlattenFn` function and its type is `Flat[List[T2], List[U2]]`. Thus `T2` = `Int` and `U2` = `U3` (that we still need to infer).

Now, if we weant to be able to use `recFlatten` we must provide it a parameter `f`. **Here is the trick**. You can either use an implicit of type `Flat[Int, U2]` **or** the default value of type `Int => List[Int]`. Let us look about the available implicits. As explained before `recFlattenFn` can provide a `Flat[List[T2], U2]` (for a new `T2` and `U2`) object. It does not fit the expected signature of `f`at this point. Thus, no implicit are a good candidate here and we must use the default argument. As the type of the default argument is  Int => List[Int], `U2`and `U3` are `Int` and there we go.

Hope that this long prose will help. I leave you with the resolution of `res1` and `res2`.