# "unlist" in scala (e.g flattening a sequence of sequences of sequences...)

Tags: scala, nested-lists, flatten

Is there a simple way in Scala to flatten or "unlist" a nested sequence of sequences of sequences (etc.) of something into just a simple sequence of those things, without any nesting structure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic, type-safe way to flatten arbitrarily nested collections in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160596/generic-type-safe-way-to-flatten-arbitrarily-nested-collections-in-scala)

Comment: See also the discussion in my somewhat related answer about a deep reverse [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12648663/334519).

Comment: The easiest way that occurs to me is to run the provided flatten function in a loop until its output equals its input.  I think most collections have a flatten function but I only checked List, Seq and Array.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a flatten` method which converts a deeply nested into a sequence.

Its easy to write a simple recursive function to do this

```
def flatten(ls: List[Any]): List[Any] = ls flatMap {
    case ms: List[_] => flatten(ms)
    case e => List(e)
  } 
 val a =  List(List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)),List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
 flatten(a)

 //> res0: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: This works well in a pinch, but the solution provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160596/generic-type-safe-way-to-flatten-arbitrarily-nested-collections-in-scala is type safe

Comment: Sorry for the nube question, but shouldn't you write `+Any`?

Comment: @BenReich - OP wanted a simple way and the solution given in your link is overly complicated for a simple case(i.e if it is a nesting of only Lists etc)

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg - It will not even compile with +Any :) Sorry, but I don't know what you are trying to do

Comment: @mohit I agree -- I just meant to say that there is a typesafe option available, so if this is a common problem, that option is preferable!

Comment: @mohit would that method accept `List[Integer]`, for example? I meant something like `List<?>` in Java, which is equivalent to `List<? extends Object>`.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg - Yes, it will accept. The only issue is that you will not get back List[Integer] but List[Any] with this method. Hence, not a typesafe solution as pointed out by Ben

Comment: @mohit Of course, I don't expect `List[Integer]` to be returned here, the statement of the problem doesn't allow us to determine output type correctly, isn't it?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg The link that Ben has pointed out will return List[Integer] . The idea is that if you have List[List[List[Int]]] (arbitrarily nested list of ints), then flatten should maintain the type. After flatten,you should get List[Int] which will be the result if you use multiple built  in flatten method like List[List[List[Int]]]().flatten.flatten.